# Qt application crashes when calling update multiple times

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, paintevent

I have an application with which I can draw a fractal using `QPainter`.
The `paintEvent` function is the following:

```
void SimulationWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen my_pen;
    initPainter(painter,my_pen);
    initCoordsystem(painter);
    if(m_mode == TRACE)
    {
        drawTrajectory(painter,my_pen);
    }
    else if(m_mode == FRACTAL)
    {
        drawFractal(painter, my_pen);
    }

    /*if(!m_isFinished)
    {
        update();
    }*/
}
```

In this version, where the last `if` is commented out, it seems to work fine.
Otherwise it would start to draw the fractal continuously during running (until `m_isFinished` is true), but one second after starting, it crashes.
The `drawFractal` function does only the drawing of the fractal based on continuously calculated results by an other function called computeFractal, which is running in an other thread. The `m_isFinished` boolean variable is set false at the beginning of this function, and at the end it is set true.

I am really confused with this, can somebody tell me please what can be the cause of the crash? Maybe because of the computeFractal runs on a different thread?
(`QtConcurrent::run(this -> m_simulationwindow, &SimulationWindow::computeFractal);`)

EDIT:

```
void SimulationWindow::drawFractal(QPainter &painter, QPen &my_pen)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < m_colors.size(); ++i)
   {
       if(m_colors[i] == 0)
       {
           my_pen.setColor(Qt::red);
           painter.setPen(my_pen);
           painter.drawPoint(m_positions[i]);
       }

       else if(m_colors[i] == 1)
       {
           my_pen.setColor(Qt::green);
           painter.setPen(my_pen);
           painter.drawPoint(m_positions[i]);
       }

       else if(m_colors[i] == 2)
       {
           my_pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
           painter.setPen(my_pen);
           painter.drawPoint(m_positions[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

`drawTrajectory` is not called at all in this case.

Comment: Where does it crash exactly? Did you try running the program in a debugger? Also could you post the code of your two functions drawTrajectory and drawFractal?

Comment: @this.lau_ : I added that you requested. At the moment I don't know where it crashes.

Comment: Are you sure that m_positions is exactly the same size as m_colors? Maybe add some sanity check at the top of your drawFractal function while you're debugging.

Comment: Who says it crashes in drawFractal? There are also initPainter and initCoordsystem

Comment: @this.lau_ I think you found out the reason of the crushes.
The size of m_positions can be smaller than the size of m_colors, since these sizes are always being updated because on the other thread the calculation continues, and sometimes the loop variable is bigger than the size of m_positions. (m_colors and positions are std::vector-s)
Thank you for finding this out! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: `update()` actually schedule's a `paintEvent()`, meaning that it does not cause an infinite recursion. Only `repaint()` would cause that.

**Suggestion**:

You could setup a `QTimer` that every bit of a second calls update, and then control your rendering execution/framerate this way.

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout(), this, SLOT(myUpdate()));
timer->start(1000f/60f);  //every 1/60 of a second it times out

void MyWindow::myUpdate()
{ 
    //do your logic here
    update();
}
```

And then on `paintEvent()` you should leave only the actual rendering.

EDIT: Qt has other solutions to control time and that could help you render, e.g. [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qelapsedtimer.html)

Comment: I tried your method, unfortunately it didn't work. I started the timer with start(1000.0f) so the update was called in every second, but the update() was called only 3 times, and it crashed. Perhaps something else causes the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried running in Debug mode, does it show where it crashes?

Comment: Every time update() is called, paintEvent() is also called. **WRONG** From the Qt docs: **Warning:** If you call repaint() in a function which may itself be called from paintEvent(), you may get infinite recursion. The update() function never causes recursion.

Comment: @KuramaYoko I found out the following: The bigger amounts of times the timer timeouts, the less likely the application crashes.

Comment: @Greenflow, you are right. Seems like I didn't remember this concept completely. I will update my answer to remove this affirmation.

Comment: @zerge this is quite strange. maybe the threads are not behaving they way you would expect. Make sure that the information threads share are safe (no variable dispute, atomic operations, etc.). Otherwise you would end up crashing from time to time.

Comment: Actually I wonder why his code compiles at all. **QtConcurrent::run(this -> m_simulationwindow, &SimulationWindow::computeFractal);)**??? The first parameter of QtConcurrent::run is a QThreadPool pointer. SimulationWindow is a QThreadPool? Sound scary... very scary.

Comment: @Greenflow computeFractal is a member function of m_simulationwindow, whose type is a SimulationWindow, which inherits QWidget.

Comment: I did not mean computeFractal. I meant this -> m_simulationwindow. I wonder how you pass it to QtConcurrent::run. 1. QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(Function function, ...); 2. QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(QThreadPool * pool, Function function, ...). So, how do you pass a QWidget to a QThreadPool pointer?